# Can an aircraft be issued a standard airworthiness certificate after being operated under and experimental certificate?

Tags: faa-regulations, flight-testing, experimental-aircraft

14 CFR, §21.191 (b) states that experimental airworthiness certificates can be used when:

> **Showing compliance with regulations.** Conducting flight tests and other operations to show compliance with the airworthiness regulations including flights to show compliance for issuance of type and supplemental type certificates (...)

Can the aircraft that is used for such testing be converted back to a standard airworthiness certificate after testing is complete?

Example scenario: Manufacturer A is developing a new autopilot to be offered as an after-market modification (along with the necessary STC). The manufacturer purchases an aircraft with a standard airworthiness certificate, installs the prototype avionics hardware, obtains an experimental certificate, and performs the necessary testing. Once complete, he manufacturer would like to return the test aircraft back to the condition it was before obtaining the experimental certificate in order to sell it with a standard airworthiness certificate.

Is that possible? If so, what would the manufacturer need to do in order to demonstrate that the aircraft was not operated outside of the limits of the standard airworthiness certificate while under the experimental certification? What FAA documentation exists that would provide guidance on this?

Comment: Not posting as an answer because I can't give you an answer to question 3, but yes an OEM will use an aircraft for test and later restore its AW cert and sell it to an operator. They won't do this with prototype a/c used for the original development testing, but will do so with production models that are transferred to the Experimental organization for cert testing of variants or systems.  All that's required is to make the a/c conform to requirements of its TC. That means restoring it to its certified config, and performing all maint/mods/tests as required.

Comment: Thank you @JohnK, makes sense. Is there any concern about the aircraft having been stressed beyond limits? E.g. the autopilot development resulted in a full scale control surface deflection that stressed the airframe beyond its g-limits. Restoring the physical attributes would result in the introduction of a non-airworthy (?) aircraft...

Comment: No because with a metal structure, for a one time overload, if the structure did not exceed its elastic limits, that is, if it's not permanently bent, it's good to go.  I know of an aircraft with the OEM I used to work for (not Boeing) that was overstressed on a production test flight because of some mishandling, and exceeded the technical negative G limits, but nothing was bent out of shape and the airplane was delivered to the customer after some inspections (and I'm pretty sure the customer was informed and given some price relief as compensation).